# Iterators on sequences

Tags: python

I want to ask how is the iterator in python designed? I have read that when the iterator is used it returns single values of the sequence of an iterable it represents upon the call of **next** or next(). And this way it does not need to copy the full iterable and therefore occupy memory. Exactly how can you return single values of a sequence object like list, string or mapping objects like dictionaries? Does it store pointers to the original sequence datastructure contents and then have a method called next which increments the pointer?

Thanks

> In Python 3, however, zip() returns an iterator. This object yields
> tuples on demand and can be traversed only once. The iteration ends
> with a StopIteration exception once the shortest input iterable is
> exhausted. If you supply no arguments to zip(), then the function
> returns an empty iterator:

Answer (score 2):

An iterator is *just* a class that defines `__next__`. That's it (though all iterators should also be iterable by defining `__iter__ = lambda self: self` as well). It's entirely *how* `__next__` is defined that defines the behavior of the iterator.

You can create an iterator over a constant sequence

```
 class Ones:
     def __iter__(self):
         return self

     def __next__(self):
         return 1
```

or you can create an iterator that walks through some *iterable* value. It's the iterator that keeps track of which value to return next, from the values supplied by the iterable. Here's a simplified version of `list_iterator`, which is the built-in type of which `list.__iter__` return values.

```
class list_iterator:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i == len(self.lst):
            raise StopIteration

        x = self.lst[self.i]
        self.i += 1
        return x

x = [1,2,3]

# prints 1, then 2, then 3
for v in list_iterator(x):
    print(v)
```